# 1 line function to get middle letters, syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to write a one-line function that will take the input string and get the middle letter/letters depending on if the string is even or uneven. I get an error code saying there's a syntax error at the first len(s) after the else if. The third line of code should continue on the second line.

**The code:**

```
def get_middle(s):
    return m = s[int(len(s/2))] if type(len(s)/2) is float else if 
    s[int(len(s)/2)-1:int(len(s)/2)]
```

**The ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from solution import *
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 2
    return m = s[len(s/2)] if type(len(s)/2) is float else if                            
      s[int(len(s)/2)-1:int(len(s)/2)]             
           ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what the heck are you writing? Just write it out in multiple lines first.

Comment: The `else if` is the problem. The correct syntax of the ternary if operator is `A if condition else B`. You have an extra `if` where `B` should be

Comment: `else if` is invalid syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type(len(s)/2) is float` is not a check for even-odd length, as you can see below, both even and odd string lengths evaluate to True for the check you had, because both divisions are float values
`4/2 = 2.0` and `5/2=2.5`

```
In [16]: s = 'abcd'                                                                                                                                                               

In [17]: type(len(s)/2) is float                                                                                                                                                  
Out[17]: True

In [18]: s = 'abcde'                                                                                                                                                              

In [19]: type(len(s)/2) is float                                                                                                                                                  
Out[19]: True
```

Why not keep things simple by checking divisibility by 2 for even/odd length.
Check if the number is length is odd or even, and select middle characters accordingly.

```
def get_middle(s):

    #If even length, select 2 characters
    if len(s)%2 == 0:
        return s[int(len(s)/2)-1:int(len(s)/2)+1]
    #If odd length, select 1 character
    else:
        return s[int(len(s)/2)]

print(get_middle('a'))
print(get_middle('ab'))
print(get_middle('abc'))
print(get_middle('abcd'))
print(get_middle('abcde'))
```

The output will be

```
a
ab
b
bc
c
```

From here, we can easily write the one liner

```
def get_middle(s):

    return s[int(len(s)/2)-1:int(len(s)/2)+1] if len(s)%2 == 0 else s[int(len(s)/2)]
```

Comment: Oh god the horror realizing `type(len(s)/2) is float` is meant to be a test for even/odd length...

Answer (score 2):

The guys in the comments and other answers already answered your question but I want to extend them a bit with some life-style advice. Yes, the issue at hand is that you shouldn't have `else if` at the end, the correct syntax is `foo if condition else bar`. And also `type(len(s)) is Float` is an absurd way to check for oddness. Hopefully, you already got that from the comments.

However, I want to argue that writing things on 1 line just so you can brag about how smart you are is a very detrimental practice. [Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-7.html#%_chap_Temp_4). Unless, you can truly make that one liner understandable, it makes no sense to write it like you did - rather prefer to write it on multiple lines to make any errors obvious. Prefer to think about the other people that will be reading this code more than 'oh, see how cool is that'.

Now if you really insist on writing short and concise code, that's ok and here's how you can actually rewrite the thing to be a meaningful one liner:

```
from math import ceil

def get_middle(s):
    return s[ceil(len(s)/2 - 1): ceil(len(s)/2)]
```

I'll let you figure out why that works on your own.

Comment: `ceil` needs to be imported from `math`.

Comment: @knh190, fair enough, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has syntax error because `if` cannot be on the second line unless you escape the new line and only `expr if cond else expr` is valid inline if-statement:

```
foo() if condition \
     else bar()
```

And there's something you'll probably like: [onelinerizer](https://github.com/csvoss/onelinerizer)

---

Original post has another problem with even/odd check. To solve it in one line:

```
def get_middle(s):
    return m = s[int(len(s/2))] if len(s)%2 != 0 else s[int(len(s)/2)-1:int(len(s)/2)]
```

Here uses `%2` to get remainder.

Though comments saying `int(len(s)/2)` would fail, also it's not guaranteed to be floor of division, as far as I see it's equivalent as `len(s)//2`:

```
def get_middle(s):
    return m = s[len(s)//2] if len(s)%2 != 0 else s[len(s)//2-1:len(s)//2]
```

Comment: From the question: "The third line of code should continue on the second line."

Comment: @GPhilo that doesn't make sense, if it's `the third line` how can it continue on `the second line`? And the title of question said `one line function`. Your debate doesn't stand for a reason for a downvote.

Comment: What the OP means is, the return statement is all on one line: `return m = s[int(len(s/2))] if type(len(s)/2) is float else if s[int(len(s)/2)-1:int(len(s)/2)]`

Comment: No, the problem is not that. The OP split the statement to make it fit in the page without scrolling, in his code the line is just one (he's pretty clear stating he has a **one**liner)

Comment: int(len(s/2)) --> this would fail

Comment: @Nithin I don't see a difference between `len(s)//2` though theoretically it's possible to fail. (my tests did not fail. Python 3.7)

Comment: @knh190 Never mind. Just saw the latest edit. Your earlier post had len(s/2) which would fail as you were dividing the string by 2